# Best practices for modeling/UV mapping an object that will be duplicated multiple times

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, shaders

I am still new to blender and am trying to find some best practices to help reduce the amount of headaches I end up with. My current issue I have gemstone object that I will be duplicating multiple times to create my finished product. Is it better to model it, texture/shader it, UV map it and then duplicate it (My thinking being that everything else I did to it will duplicate with it) or is there a better way to reduce the amount of repeat work I have to do? Also since the gemstone is all the "same" object just in different locations is it ok to combine them into one "mesh object" or should I keep them separate?

Comment: Create it, then duplicate it with alt D (not shift D), this way you will have linked-duplications, it makes your file lighter, and if you select any of these linked-duplications, you can modify it and it will be replicated on all the other instances

Comment: And just to add to @moonboots' comment - you can give different material (e.g. color) to each duplicate, but they'll still all carry the same UV map :).

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.